# ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1 when doing DELETE

Tags: python, ms-access

I have this query:

`query_del = '''DELETE * FROM Students WHERE Students.[last_name] = "Q";'''`

And I'm doing this for execute:

```
conn= pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\XXX\Database.accdb;')

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(query_del)
curs.commit()
```

But I'm getting this error:

`ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1`

The database is current like:

ID  last_name   first_name  E-mail Address

3   Buuuu   B   C
4   Cuuuu   C   D
70  W   W
72  W   W
74  W   W
76  W   W
78  W   W
80  W   W
82  W   W
84  W   W
86  W   W
87  Q   Q
88  W   W
89  Q   Q
90  W   W

EDIT 1:
The query this way works:

`query_del = '''DELETE * FROM Students WHERE Students.[last_name] = 'Q';'''`

But I really need to have double quotes in the variables because I have some last names like `x'xxx'x` so I don't know how to DELETE them. The query with simple a double quotes works well in Access:

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE Students.[last_name] = "W"; #Works in Access
DELETE FROM Students WHERE Students.[last_name] = 'W'; #Also Works in Access
```

How can I translate this to python and to pyodbc?

Comment: Regarding the issue with text values which include an apostrophe, switch to a [parameter query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209618/77335)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:
`query_del = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE [last_name] = 'Q'"`

Notice the swap of quote and apostrophe delimiters. The * wildcard for fields is not necessary although shouldn't hurt.

If hard coding a value with apostrophe then double the aprostrophe so it is escaped and forced to be seen as literal text: `='x''x'`. If coding a dynamic input by referencing a control on form, must concatenate and use Replace to handle possibility of apostrophe in data:

`query_del = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE [last_name] = '" & Replace(Me.tbxName, "'", "''") & "'"`

Or use parameters - review [How do I use SQL parameters with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410455/how-do-i-use-sql-parameters-with-python)

The variable set is `query_del` but execute references `query` so try:
`curs.execute(query_del)`

Comment: The reason this works, of course, is that the ODBC driver has ANSI quotes on by default, so is interpreting `"Q"` as a field name, not as a literal string

Comment: So what if I want to delete a last name that is:  x'xxx? I can't do it with 'x'xxx', I need to do it like "x'xxx"

Answer (score 0):

So in Delphi, Java or C# is essential to double quote values:

```
   cmd:= CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
   sQuery:= 'Update Table1 set FirstName = ''maXbox5'' where Int = 4';
   //sQuery:= 'select * from Table1 where FirstName = ''Max''';
   cmd.CommandText:= squery;
   cmd.CommandType:= adCmdText
```